# What are synonyms for 'disputed regions'?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, terminology

I would like to know what else I can use instead of '*disputed regions*', I've used *conflicted territories*, but that doesn't sound right. Are there any other combinations of two words that have the same meaning as '*disputed regions*'?

Comment: What's wrong with *disputed region* in the first place? It's a common phrase. Can you give an example of why you would want to use something different?

Comment: (Either *unresolved ownership* or *war zone* could mean the same thing, but only based on context—and the sentence construction might also need to be changed.)

Comment: @JasonBassford i'm writing an essay and i would like to avoid repetition

Comment: Using multiple words and phrases to express the same thing can actually be a *bad* idea when it comes to formal writing. But, that aside, you still need to provide some context by putting a sentence, and possibly surrounding sentences, into your question. (If your goal is to avoid repetition, provide an example of the repetition you want to avoid—not just the phrase on its own.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**contested** land(s) [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/contested)

> 1. To compete or strive for; struggle to gain or control: trade routes that were contested by competing cultures.

Answer (score 0):

When the region is controlled by one party A, but it historically belonged to another party B, the region is called an **irridenta**. According to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/irridenta):

> a region that is ethnically or historically tied to one country, but which is ruled by another

Attribution: Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers